# angularjs: $timeout usage (inside of service)

Tags: angularjs, service, timeout, closures

I'm trying to make a little notifier, that informs about typical situations: need authorization, changes saved etc. Notices are shown for 3 seconds and disappear, if user didn't click on it (if notice clicked, it disappears immediatly).
Documentation is not very informative.
How should i use `$timeout`, to call `close();` after 3 seconds?
And how can i put a variable *`(nId)`* into function? I tried with closure `(*function(){return function(){}}*)` in default `setTimeOut()`, but unsuccessfully.

```
myApp.controller('noticesCtrl',
    function noticesCtrl($scope, $rootScope, noticesData){
        $rootScope.notices = [];
        $scope.closeNotice = function(nId){
            noticesData.close(nId);
        };
    });

myApp.factory('noticesData', function($rootScope, $timeout){
    return{
        add: function(type, text){
            var nId = $rootScope.notices.length + 1;
            $rootScope.notices.push({id: nId, type:type, text:text+nId});
            // call close function with 3sec. delay; how?
        },
        close: function(nId){
            angular.forEach($rootScope.notices, function(notice, key){
                if(notice.id == nId){
                    $rootScope.notices.splice(key,1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) JS library? It has several options and it shows quite nice notifications. I just wrapped that in a service in order to use it in AngularJS. (And no, I'm not involved with the team :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myApp.factory('noticesData', function($rootScope, $timeout){
    var obj = {};
    obj.add = function(type, text){
        var nId = $rootScope.notices.length + 1;
        $rootScope.notices.push({id: nId, type:type, text:text+nId});
        $timeout(function(){
            obj.close(nId);
        },3000);
    }
    obj.close = function(nId){
        angular.forEach($rootScope.notices, function(notice, key){
            if(notice.id == nId){
                $rootScope.notices.splice(key,1);
            }
        });
    }
    return obj; 
});
```

Comment: I dont think I get what you are trying to say but the object must be instantiated before you can use any of its contained methods.

Comment: I only say, that call this.close() works well and i thought, that there exists a way to call this.close() with $timeout delay (it doesn't works, but doesn't reports about error too).
Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Heres how to do it

```
$timeout(function () {

    // do something

}, 50);
```